# Django: How to loop through query set and change the boolean field to True in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to loop through a queryset in django and turn all the boolean fields in the queryset to true.

I want to turn this booleans to True on the success_page, so i tried doing it like this

```
@login_required
def PaymentSuccessView(request):
    ...
    order = get_object_or_404(CartOrder, stripe_payment_intent=session.id)
    cart_order_items = CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
    for c in cart_order_items:
        c.paid = True
        c.save()
        
    return render(request, "payment/payment_success.html", {"order": order})
```

The problem is that, this still does not work even after i get redirected to the success page on successful transaction.

---

I also tried doing this in the model, i am not sure if it's the right way to do this, but i tried it and it still did not work

```
class CartOrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(CartOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.order.payment_status == "paid":
            self.paid = True
         
        return super(CartOrderItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

These are my model fields

```
class CartOrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(CartOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...


class CartOrder(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ManyToManyField(Vendor)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="buyer")
    stripe_payment_intent = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I have looked at other SO answers and they did not answer my question, that is why i am asking a new question

Comment: I see there is no payment_status attribute in CartOrder model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.update()` method to update all items in the queryset. In your case something like:

```
CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order).update(paid=True)
```

So the full function might be like:

```
@login_required
def PaymentSuccessView(request):
    ...
    order = get_object_or_404(CartOrder, stripe_payment_intent=session.id)
    CartOrderItem.objects.filter(order=order).update(paid=True)
        
    return render(request, "payment/payment_success.html", {"order": order})
```

See the documentation for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: it should work however he needs to explain his problem so that we can help him. according to the current scenario, he is also doing it the right way but somehow it is not saving.

Comment: @djangodeveloper I suspect there may have been more in the 'save' method of CartOrderItem which was removed for posting here. I'd bet there was an error in logic there we're not seeing. If each cart item needed some additional logic run on save, addressing why the loop and save each didn't work would be required. From the code in the op it does look like it should work as is. I'd bet that order's `payment_status` is not being set to "paid" or some other code not shown here is being run in the `save`.